# jQuery .each display array data - cannot work it out

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to loop through all this array data but it won't work out how to display it all via jquery using the .each function? Can someone help me out?

ARRAY:

```
{
    "ListOrdersResult": {
        "Orders": {
            "Order": [
                {
                    "ShipmentServiceLevelCategory": "Standard",
                    "OrderTotal": {
                        "Amount": "29.00",
                        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
                    },
                    "ShipServiceLevel": "Std UK Dom",
                    "LatestShipDate": "2013-11-28T23:59:59Z",
                    "MarketplaceId": "A1F83G8C2ARO7P",
                    "SalesChannel": "Amazon.co.uk",
                    "ShippingAddress": {
                        "Phone": "0800 000 0000",
                        "PostalCode": "A11 H11",
                        "Name": "stephanie ross",
                        "CountryCode": "GB",
                        "StateOrRegion": "regiion",
                        "AddressLine2": "cairnbulg",
                        "AddressLine1": "loco 2222 name",
                        "City": "fraserburgh"
                    },
                    "ShippedByAmazonTFM": "false",
                    "OrderType": "StandardOrder",
                    "FulfillmentChannel": "MFN",
                    "BuyerEmail": "c9tkdmn724jpgkd@blahblah.com",
                    "OrderStatus": "Shipped",
                    "BuyerName": "custom A Ross",
                    "LastUpdateDate": "2013-11-27T14:26:53Z",
                    "EarliestShipDate": "2013-11-27T00:00:00Z",
                    "PurchaseDate": "2013-11-26T22:25:39Z",
                    "NumberOfItemsUnshipped": "0",
                    "AmazonOrderId": "205-8108202-4976362",
                    "NumberOfItemsShipped": "1",
                    "PaymentMethod": "Other"
                },
                {
                    "ShipmentServiceLevelCategory": "Standard",
                    "OrderTotal": {
                        "Amount": "29.00",
                        "CurrencyCode": "GBP"
                    },
                    "ShipServiceLevel": "Std UK Dom",
                    "LatestShipDate": "2013-11-28T23:59:59Z",
                    "MarketplaceId": "A1F83G8C2ARO7P",
                    "SalesChannel": "Amazon.co.uk",
                    "ShippingAddress": {
                        "Phone": "0800 000 0000",
                        "PostalCode": "A11 H11",
                        "Name": "stephanie ross",
                        "CountryCode": "GB",
                        "StateOrRegion": "regiion",
                        "AddressLine2": "cairnbulg",
                        "AddressLine1": "loco 2222 name",
                        "City": "fraserburgh"
                    },
                    "ShippedByAmazonTFM": "false",
                    "OrderType": "StandardOrder",
                    "FulfillmentChannel": "MFN",
                    "BuyerEmail": "c9tkdmn724jpgkd@blahblah.com",
                    "OrderStatus": "Shipped",
                    "BuyerName": "custom A Ross",
                    "LastUpdateDate": "2013-11-27T14:26:53Z",
                    "EarliestShipDate": "2013-11-27T00:00:00Z",
                    "PurchaseDate": "2013-11-26T22:25:39Z",
                    "NumberOfItemsUnshipped": "0",
                    "AmazonOrderId": "205-8108202-4976362",
                    "NumberOfItemsShipped": "1",
                    "PaymentMethod": "Other"
                }
            ]
        },
        "CreatedBefore": "2014-05-14T01:12:05Z"
    },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "46f5c980-91e6-44d3-bc9d-668976855862"
    },
    "xmlns": "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01"
}
```

CURRENT JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('functions/ListOrders.php', function(xml){ 
    var newOrders = $.xml2json(xml);
    $.each(newOrders.Orders.Order, function(index, value) { 
      console.log(value);
      console.log(value.ShipmentServiceLevelCategory);
    });
    $('body').text(JSON.stringify(newOrders));
  });
});
```

Comment: try `$.each(newOrders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order`

Comment: What's not working? Any errors?

Comment: i get TypeError: newOrders.Orders is undefined
$.each(newOrders.Orders.Order, function(index, value) {

Comment: Your JSON looks invalid (for starters no matching end ] for Orders)

Comment: Arun's solution may work. Might help you to try `console.log(newOrders);` to see what it looks like before doing the `$.each()` call.

Comment: Dump your json into this, and fix the errors: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yea might of been me copying it in  here but it is valid this end

Comment: on console log it is all there, not sure how to paste from console log of firebug to hear though

Comment: @Andrew: JSON is Valid - might from my example just missed something out as changed it as was live client data but let me update the post example with dummy data

Comment: Have updated correct JSON data

Comment: this seems to work but when i do the html output on the body it only shows 1 and in the console shows them all

Comment: $.get('functions/ListOrders.php', function(xml){ 
    var newOrders = $.xml2json(xml);
    $.each(newOrders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order, function(index, value) { 
     console.log(value.AmazonOrderId);
     $('body').text(value.AmazonOrderId);
    });
   });

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the first element of the JSON object:

Change

```
 $.each(newOrders.Orders.Order, function(index, value) {
```

To

```
 $.each(newOrders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order, function(index, value) {
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/9YU3H/

Comment: Thanks, that is what i done and worked great however i get a JS error if i go a little deeper... for example value.OrderTotal.Amount fails and i get: TypeError: value.OrderTotal is undefined any ideas on why it does that? im trying value.OrderTotal.Amount in the JS but its even complaining on a JS error just with OrderTotal alone but is there in the array. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any issues, I updated the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9YU3H/1/

Take a look